# No columns are created for the text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create columns for my text, I've divided it into three parts, but the columns just won't create. Below is all the code, hope for help.

I tried to make the simplest columns, according to various tutorials, but some of them are broken, and some do not work at all

Maybe the problem is in the background, which is overflowing, but I'm not sure.

[image: columns position]

```css
p {
    color: white;
    width: 400px; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative; 
    left: 75px; 
    top: 110px
   }

  /* column text instllningar*/

  .block {
    margin: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-rule: 300px;
    columns: 4 150px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    column-rule: 2px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
            width: auto;
            height: 3000px;
            font-size: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            margin: auto;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: linear-gradient(45deg, #30cfd0, #330867, #C4E0E5);
            background-size: 200%;
            animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
        }
        @keyframes gradient {
            0% {
                background-position: 0 50%;
            }
            50% {
                background-position: 100% 50%;
            }
            100%{
                background-position: 0 50%;
            } 
        }

    </style>
    <link href="about_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    <div class="full-page-width">
        <div class="center-content-container">
            <div class="content-container">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="extended-content-container">
                <div class="extended-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-flex">
    <div class="container"> 
    <a href="htmlcode.html"><iconify-icon class="dollar" icon="fa:dollar" style="color: #83bf4f;" width="50" height="50"></a></iconify-icon>
    <a href="htmlcode.html"><iconify-icon class="hand" icon="fa-solid:hand-holding" style="color: white;" width="70" height="70"></a></iconify-icon>  
    </div>
</div>  
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.0-beta.3/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>  

    <div class="hero">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">
        <p> text </p> 
                        
        <p>     text </p> 

        <p>   text </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Run it through a validator.

Comment: Hii, you have created columns! good work. Now try to tidy up your code and see if you need everything in there, for example - delete all the CSS of the p tag and see the text go back to its place inside the block element and on the left side of your page. read this on columns https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: I tried removing the .p in the css, but the line does not appear

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put `paragraphs` there and expect them to create columns automatically.

there are no columns because you didn't add any `style` to the text `container` and its default `display` is block.

anyway, I suggest using `display flex` because it's suitable for responsive design.

here I styled your `text container` to make columns, then I added `media query` to style it vertically for mobile view.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  width: auto;
  height: 3000px;
  font-size: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #30cfd0, #330867, #C4E0E5);
  background-size: 200%;
  animation: gradient 10s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block p {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  min-width: 33.3%;
}

@media only screen and ( max-width: 700px) {
  .block {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<div class="full-page-width">
  <div class="center-content-container">
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="extended-content-container">
      <div class="extended-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="htmlcode.html">
      <iconify-icon class="dollar" icon="fa:dollar" style="color: #83bf4f;" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    </iconify-icon>
    <a href="htmlcode.html">
      <iconify-icon class="hand" icon="fa-solid:hand-holding" style="color: white;" width="70" height="70">
    </a>
    </iconify-icon>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/iconify-icon/1.0.0-beta.3/iconify-icon.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <p> text </p>

    <p> text </p>

    <p> text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your have a problem with the 'relative' keyword.
Try to use it when you want an element to be positionned relatively to an absolute positionned element.
For your case, just remove the `position: relative` from your `p` rule and everything will be fine